# How to add 'depends:' rule to many fields in jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have used this rule to validate the user billing address if he wants a bill (the input #billyes is checked), this is my current code:

```
                //BILLING VALIDATION
                legal_id: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                          return $('#billyes').is(":checked");
                        }
                    }
                 },
                 billing_name: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                          return $('#billyes').is(":checked");
                        }
                    }
                 },
                 billing_adress: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                          return $('#billyes').is(":checked");
                        }
                    }
                 },

                 .... ETC
```

It is repeated too the line `return $('#billyes').is(":checked");`

I want to do something like this:

```
                //BILLING VALIDATION
                legal_id,billing_name,billing_adress,etc: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                          return $('#billyes').is(":checked");
                        }
                    }
                 }
```

Is this possible? Is there any alternative?

Thanks you.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in single line according to their documentation, not sure though.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
legal_id,billing_name,billing_adress,etc: {
```

Within the `.validate()` method, you **cannot** do anything like that at all.  The object literal within the `rules` option must be `key:value` pairs where the `key` can only be a single field `name`.

However, there is a way to apply the same rule to multiple fields at once:

You can combine the `.rules()` method with a jQuery `.each()`.  But you'll need a clever jQuery selector to target them all at once.  Like a "starts with" selector or a `class`.  You can't use "starts with `billing_`" since you also have `legal_id`, so you'll need to assign a `class` to these fields or do something else.

```
$('.yourFields').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return $('#billyes').is(":checked");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Otherwise, no, within the `.validate()` method, there is no shortcut.